# Vue JS - How to display image with dynamic URL without getting an error?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When I try to show an image with dynamic URL, that is coming from an API call initially I get an error in the console. After a few moments the image is loaded. Is there a way to prevent that error? I use beforeCreate hook for the API call. Any help will be appreciated.

HTML

```
<img :src="userAvatarURL" class="img-fluid avatar">
```

Javascript

```
export default {
    beforeCreate() {
        this.$store.dispatch('getUser');
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState({
            user: 'user',
        }),
        userAvatarURL: {
            get: function () {
                return window.axios.defaults.baseURL+'/storage/user_avatars/'+this.user.avatar;
            }
        }
    }
```

Error in network tab of the console

```
GET http://api.aaa/storage/user_avatars/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply display this image when `user.avatar` is defined, e.g. :

```
<img v-if="user.avatar" :src="userAvatarURL" class="img-fluid avatar">
```